# How can I change date and time of photos on iOS?

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone 7 running iOS 13.

For some reason, many of the photos are time stamped in 2045. I've not found a single linkable article explaining how to do this.

Can I change future date / mislabeled photos from February 2045 to August 2012?

Comment: Can we presume you don’t sync photos to the cloud and also presume you took all the photos on this specific phone? The [help] has info on editing your research and details into the body if no one answers after a week or three.

Comment: Do you [have a Mac computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215536/is-it-possible-to-update-timestamps-on-multiple-photos-using-new-photos-app)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this photo at a time by first downloading the [Exif Metadata app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/exif-metadata/id1455197364). Once this app is installed, open it and allow it to access your photos. Select a photo and then near the bottom of the screen, you'll see EXIF followed by metadata. Scroll all the way to the bottom and you should see an Edit Exif button. Press this button and press on the date of the image. it should be the 1st displayed line. You'll be able to change the date.

The app is free from the app store. it has an in-app purchase for the pro version.  The pro version claims you can do multiple files at once. I haven't figured out how.

If you have a Mac computer there is a way to change the date on all at once. Just let me know, in the comments, if you need this.